# How to real time display input value with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
<span id="display"></span>
```

So that when user enter something inside "#name",will show it in "#display"

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could simply set input value to the inner [`text`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text) or [`html`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html) of the #display element, on the [`keyup`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keyup) event:

```
$('#name').keyup(function () {
  $('#display').text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: this does not consider the user pasting using the mouse, see answers below

Answer (score 19):

A realtime fancy solution for jquery >= 1.9

```
$("#input-id").on("change keyup paste", function(){
    dosomething();
})
```

if you also want to detect "click" event, just:

```
$("#input-id").on("change keyup paste click", function(){
    dosomething();
})
```

if your jquery <=1.4, just use "live" instead of "on".

Comment: This covers more cases, including 'paste', which the accpeted answer does not.

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#name').keyup(function() {
    $('#display').text($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers are, of course, correct. I would only add that you may want to prefer to use the `keydown` event because the changes will appear sooner:

```
$('#name').keydown(function() {
    $('#display').text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Keydown events occur before the character is actually entered, so this solution delays the output by one character (`#display` will never show the most recently typed character in `#name`)

Answer (score 0):

**code.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#name').keyup(function(){
    var type_content = $(this).val();
    $('#display').text(type_content);
});


});
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<span id="display"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).